# Cover a DIV with a Image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div in my code and have inserted some controls in that DIV dynamically.
Then i tried to insert an image over that.(The whole div should be covered including controls in that div).

But when i tried to do that i am only able to cover the div and unable to cover the controls in that div.

The code i have used is:

```
$('#myDIv').css('background-image', 'url("/Assets/Images/transparent-cover.png")');
```

So my question is what should i do to cover my whole div including controls in jquery.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: Would be helpful to provide a solution if you can post your relevant html, css and jQuery code. OR much better if could demonstrate using fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Plz try this one:

```
 $('#myDIv').css({'background-image':"url('/Assets/Images/transparent-cover.png')", 'background-size':"cover"});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/RNVaZ/1266/)

[DEMO 1](http://codepen.io/necolas/pen/Aksni)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is not working. Im getting the same result :(

Comment: By mistakes sorry sir @user3229075

Comment: <div id="myDIv"
     style="background-image:url("/Assets/Images/transparent-cover.png")"
></div>

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to cover elements inside your div you need to add another element that is able to do so. You could create a CSS-class with an :after-definition, that covers your div. Something like this:

```js
$('.block').hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('cover');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
}

.control {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.cover:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="control"></div>
  <div class="control"></div>
  <div class="control"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is now covering my whole div. But the problem i am facing is: it is also covering the the div that is over this div. 'code' <div id = "fullDiv"><div id ="subDiv></div></div>. Here iam applying the above code to "subDiv". But it is also assigning the same properties to the "fullDiv". Kindly resolve

Comment: Does your "subDiv" have "position: relative;" set?

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so I would appreciate if you could accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size:cover` to cover a div with background image..